# How I can get the number of online users in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can get the (count) number of online users in Django and display the number in the admin screen

should I add Boolean field in the models

```
is_online = models.BooleanField()
```

or there is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the django cache:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

With it you can store a value for each user that is determined to be online and give it an expiration time so that the record is removed when the user is not considered online anymore.

Ideally this should be made as a middleware, so that the cache is updated on every user interaction with your API.

Then when you need to know if a user is online, you only need to attempt to retrieve the record from the cache, say record `online_user_pk_1`. If the record exists, it's online, if not, then it's not online.